# 3 watt LED driver

Tags: led, constant-current, led-driver

is this schematic good for driving a 3 W LED (700 mA, 3.3 V)? 
P1 is a 12V lead-acid battery input, P2 output.[image]

Comment: Which LM5276 output voltage version are you using?

Comment: Also, what is your definition of good?  Is it good enough to work, or should it also not burn you when you touch it?

Comment: also, what is your input voltage?

Comment: Actually, i see you are using the adjustable version.  It looks like your voltage setting resistors are incorrect.

Comment: When you drop a ground symbol into the page, does it initially face up, or left? Just because the software allows you to rotate it, doesn’t mean you should. If someone didn’t know better, he might think the up-facing ground is an antenna. It just looks weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Is the *schematic* good?

No, it's not a good schematic.

Criteria for good schematics are, among many others:

1. sufficient spacing to make them easily readable
2. Improved readability by consistent alignment,
3. grouping
4. and rotation of components, as well as
5. a consistent direction of signal flow, and
6. consistent and meaningful symbols.

Regarding the most prominent shortcomings in these three categories:

1. There is no reason to pack everything as closely as you do. Your component labels should not be overlayed by wiring.
2. Why didn't you even try to put P1 and P2 on the same height, for example? R2 and R1 form some kind of voltage divider, between the SMPS output voltage and ground, right? So it would have made sense to rotate them vertically, put ground at the bottom and horizontally align them.
3. This is just one example: a good schematic would group related components together whilst putting unrelated functional units further away for clarity. So, in a good schematic, R1 would be close to U2, and not to U1.
4. Rotation of your components is *terrible*! Ground *always* points down. Never up, never sideways. Why does U2 have it's first pin the furthest down without any need?
5. It's usual to support the reader by putting the input left, the output right. This would have made it easier for me, for example, to understand what the job of the LM2576 (by the way, you missspelled the most important part in your schematic...) is, and what the job of the LM317 is.
6. Your U2 symbol isn't great. It's better to not only number pins, but give them names that clearly mark what they're doing. Also, usually, for things like that, a box with pins on both sides is a good idea. I don't know the circuit editor you're using, but this is really a standard component and you should be able to find a library that has a better symbol for the part. Something's also a bit off about your LM317 symbol – why is ADJ part of the symbol outline, but IN and OUT are clearly pin names?

## Is the *circuit* good?

Well, you don't tell us anything about the input voltage, so it's impossible to say whether you've dimensioned the inductor, the diode and smoothing cap of the LMxxxx SMPS correctly. I assume you just went and used the power supply calculator on TI's homepage, with your input voltage and a >700mA output current at something like 5V output voltage to give the LM317 some room to work with, so it's probably OK. If you didn't, do it now.

You really don't need a linear regulator just to achieve constant current. Instead, you could just, instead of using a voltage divider on the LMxxxx output voltage, sense the output current with a shunt resistor after the LEDs. That would make your *constant voltage supply* a *constant current supply*, and you could get rid of the power-wasting, finger-burning LM317. It would also eliminate the need for the HUMONGOUS C1 (as your LED really doesn't care about ripple, usually, and you just need a smaller C1 to achieve loop stability).

Comment: my input voltage is 12v (lead acid battery)

Comment: Added the critical info (input voltage) to your question. Regarding this being the first circuit you've built: that's why I pointed you to the TI website to calculate the components.